# Http to Https looping recursively in IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis, iis-8

I have a web application which was developed in ASP.net web form and hosted in IIS 10. It was in Form Authentication mode.

I have installed SSL certificate in the server IIS. But while using HTTPS redirects rule it is redirecting recursively from HTTP to HTTPS and vice versa. At last i am getting error in Browser "Too many redircts"

I have tried so many rules one by one from the web and applied in the URLRewrite but nothing works. I have given one rule here which was i tried but not works

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <clear />
          <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Actually i need my site should redirect automatically http to https. That's it.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Your Rules is right. Might be it's redirect from code I am not sure. But please verify it.

Comment: Please do a Find All for the word `Redirect` in your code and post the results.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition input be `{HTTP}` ?

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara I thought too - But it was not going inside Default.aspx page load itself. So i understood that the problem is not in the code.

Comment: @Moo-Juice i am not getting what you are meaning {HTTP}

Comment: I suggest you could try to use failed request tracing to trace rewrite rules to see what happened. Details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. I found the code from the .cs file because there only written https to http code. I have removed that code and it was working perfect. So i have used below rule only that's all

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <clear />
          <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Thanks for your support guys